# Any way to force all java applications to use a particular java setting?

Tags: java

I need to add `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true` to my java applications, otherwise they freeze up.

Is there any way to force this system wide, so I don't have to modify the configuration file/script of each java application?

Comment: Can you put this into a [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/envvars-138887.html) environment variable that is inherited by all processes that may launch your java apps?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and hackish fix, you could do something like:

```
# type java
java is /usr/bin/java
# mv /usr/bin/java{,.real}
# cat >>/usr/bin/java <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
exec java.real -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true "$@"
EOF
chmod +x /usr/bin/java
```

This replaces your java executable with a shell script that calls the real one, with its given arguments, except with that setting prepended.

Comment: Don't do such hacks. use `$PATH` and your distributions mechanisms.

Comment: It's not clear to me that there is a distribution-agnostic way to say "replace this package-controlled file with an arbitrary different one", nor even that any given distribution will have such a method at all. If the question had been specific to a given distribution, or even mentioned one, it might have been worth researching its specific mechanism.

Comment: It doesn't need to be agnostic (but `$PATH` is, and Mark mentioned another one). He only has one (unfortunately he didn't both to include which). But the way you propsed will likely be destroyed on the next update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `.properties` files in

```
/etc/java-8-openjdk
```

or the equivalent configuration directory of the JVM that you are using?